# Is there a badge for an embarrassingly bungle question?

Tags: support, badges

I've checked with the badge list but as far I can see, there's no badge for being bungly when asking a question and making a blunder so embarrassing that one's colleagues throw stuff at one.

1. Is there such?
2. Should we have such?

If "yes" to any of the above, I'd like to nominate myself immediately. Just the other day, not being a DB guy, I started developing data access layer and used *SqlDataAdapter*. Then, I got afraid that the GC is not going to work out well and asked [a very well formulated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206623/is-destroying-of-the-adapter-implied-when-using-for-connection-reaches-the-end-o), with example code and all.

The first comment I got asked me if I didn't ask that question already. Well, Precisely one year ago (give or take five days), I did, indeed. I don't know how I could miss it when googling prior to asking the question a second time! (I guess being stupid is a tempting suggestion, hehe.)

I plan to ask the same question next year to in order to keep up the tradition.   :)

Comment: We don't need to encourage negative behavior. You will be surprised how many people will post crap intentionally just to get a badge.  Those silly bits of colored pixels really motivate some people.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Naa, I don't mean to do clumsy stuff on purpose. That'd be pathetic. I mean a genuine mistake that is kind of cute in the retrospective.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do with the idea, but people will still intentionally try to do it just to try to get the badge.  I have seem people post questions with this (or similar titles) - "Please don't read this, I am trying to get the Tumbleweed badge".  No matter what, you will encourage that kind of behavior.

Comment: @KonradViltersten If I understand you right, you'd like to have something like an `epic fail` badge? I don't think this would be useful, but that's arguable of course.

Comment: It is indeed a cute mistake. But some people run behind badges. So badges aren't a good idea. Sadly, everybody isn't as sporting as you are.

Comment: Apart from attracting badge hunters for the wrong reasons, there is another problem with this idea: how would you go about *automatically* awarding this badge? What would the criteria be for the system to recognise that you earned it?

Comment: About the only one is Peer Pressure; if it's a pretty bungled question, chances are good it also got downvoted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, as obvious as it already is, I need to state it explicitly: I didn't think this through all the way to the bone. Assuming that people behave well and respect the idea behind a badge is a bit (read: almost entirely) naive. I take pride in admitting when I'm proven wrong. So I'm doing it now. (Side note: by admitting that one **is** wrong, one actually **ceases** to be wrong because the incorrect statement is thereafter claimed as such. Think about it... Never being wrong... Hmmm...)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Perhaps one should answer each suck post with an ironic "okey, mate". Every single time...   :)

Answer (score 6):

*I don't like unanswered questions so I'll answer myself by summarizing what the commenters mentioned.*

This idea is less than smart because of the three dudes:

1. Dude - why encourage making mistakes?!
2. Dude - are others going to treat it maturely?!
3. Dude - how can one automatize the process?!

All in all - it's easy to come up with better ideas than this. Now go away and post a question about *SqlDataAdapter* in a year or so...

Answer (score 1):

Why should someone be 'punished' for asking a question?

For you it might be funny and laughable, for them it may take hours to actually solve the problem.

So the answer is no, we should not have this kind of badge.